# Resource from class library and xamarin.android

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.android

**Update:** I was since able to a text file resource to the project, whose content is in json format. This seems to work without issue. Is this conventional though? I guess the question still stands.

I have a class library I wrote and tested that uses a json file. Originally I had this as simply a file accessible to the project. I can deserialize it, use it, no problem.

I've since added a xamarid.android project to my solution, developed my interface, wired things up, all is good. I also referenced the earlier class library I wrote and intend to use in the android app.

Once I execute the app and kicked off the new class though, Visual Studio stopped and complained it couldn't read the json file in question.

It made sense since the original class library project was simply outputting the file to disk on build. Android doesn't know about that location.

Things I've already tried but do not work:

Build Action: Embedded Resource/Resource/Compile
Adding the file as a *project resource*. This didn't work as now Visual Studio thinks the file is binary and I cannot deserialize it...?

For what it's worth, the error (rather obvious now):
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/Data/BattingAverageFlair.json".

```
public List<Flair> Flair = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Flair>>(File.ReadAllText("Data/BattingAverageFlair.json"));
public string GetFlair(double averge) => Flair.First(m => averge <= m.Max && averge >= m.Min).Flairtext;
```

Ideally my class library: BattingAverageCalculator should be completely independent of BattingAverage, my xamarin android app.

Thanks for any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot open files from the application package in code apart from some special cases like images and application configuration files.

Two options here:

1. If the jSon file you are talking about is a config sort of file which will be used to pass parameters to the app in development time. Use Settings in App.Config for that.
2. If you are using as a local storage or a client application database of some sort you should create the file in runtime (maybe with some hard-coded predefined values) in the Android personal library folder where you can access it later in code.

You can read and write files into local storage in this folder path:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)
```

Comment: I'm intentionally trying to keep the application and data logic (classy library) separate from the UI (xamarin.android). The json file is a database mean to be accessed at run-time and returns simple data types.

Comment: You can't abstract away file access. It's completely platform dependent. Maybe you can get a string or a stream as input in your lower level.

Comment: I was able to add the content and use the json when I added it as a project Resource, I presume because then it is wrapped up in the DLL and not external to it.

Comment: Yes yes. Use option one then you can save it but since it goes through .Net it's not really high performance. Use it only if it's a rare task.